# Ignore request to self-signed certificate

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I am using `capacitor-community/http` with ionic 5 and vuejs in order to make api requests.
Everything worked fine so far, however I could not found a way to make requests to internal ip addresses like `https:192.x.x.x` that contains a self-signed certificate.

I get the following error:

`SSLHandshakeException`

**Screenshots**
On Postman I can solve this using :

[image]

**Expected behavior**
I would like to know if it possible to disable ssl verification `capacitor-community/http`, or if you guys suggests a workaround to this situation in particular.